# How to Keep a persistent http-server open on AWS instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, remote-access

I set up a AWS Ubuntu instance running a http-server using node.js

I was wondering if its possible to log out of my remote server while persistently keeping the http-server on.

Comment: How did you come to the assume that the state of the HTTP server has anything to do with the fact that you are logged in to the box or not?

Comment: hey ! 

[link](http://i.imgur.com/cXanrpK.png)

my question is more pedesterian :( I am not sure how to exit access to my remote server without stopping my http-server.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty good tutorial that deals with keeping a node.js server running, and amongst other things, deals with running it in the background.

http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/

Answer (score 1):

Forever is a nice option (as suggested above).

Though, I recommend using AWS' [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) over EC2 (that's the service you are using now, if I got it right), it provides you an easy interface to deploy you web-server with no ssh interference and keeps it alive at all times after deployment, and also gives you some other load balancing and auto scaling features with minimum effort.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) for this. Besides keeping your http-server online it also gives you the possibility to do load balancing and other tasks.

Run

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

on your server and start your app with

```
pm2 start app.js
```

As marekful points out, logging out of your Ubuntu server will not have any effect on your http-server.